# No value present, when test method getEntityById?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

Have next problem, when i test method i have exception NoSuchElementException - > no value present

My Mock

```
@InjectMocks
    private CarServiceImpl carService;
    
    @Mock
    private CarRepository carrepo;
```

My test

```
@Test
    void getCarById() {

        Car car = new Car();
        car.setId(1L);
    
        carService.getCarById(1l);
        when(carrepo.findById(1l)).thenReturn(Optional.of(car));
        
        Car actualCar = carService.getCarById(1L);
        Assertions.assertEquals (car, actualCar);
        
}
```

And Service Layer

```
@Override
    public Car getCarById(Long id) {
        
        return carrepo.findById(id).get();
    }
```

if somebody know where is problem, please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish in this test, but you're calling `carService.getCarById(1L);` BEFORE the Mockito `when`. You also call it after but I'm guessing that the initial time you call the `getCarById(1L)` there's no value available hence the `no value present` message.

Comment: @g00glen00b - edited based on your feedback - thx

Answer (score 0):

This test will passed form me, everybody tnx!

```
  @Test
        void getCarById() {
    
            Car car = new Car();
            car.setId(1L);
        
            when(carrepo.findById(1l)).thenReturn(Optional.of(car));
            
            Car actualCar = carService.getCarById(1L);
            Assertions.assertEquals (car, actualCar);
            
        }
```

Comment: if you found any answer helpful, then don't forget to accept it. It motivates members to contribute more. + you will also see spike in your reputation too. :)